# How to display content of one site in another using PHP?

Tags: php, database, syndication

I'm trying to show contents of two websites in one another , someone suggest me to use RSS reader but my question is :

is there anything else i could try to show the contents , beside using rss  !?

i thought i can connect to the database of another website , but that didnt work /

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have control over both websites?

Comment: What kind of content are you talking about exactly? Please make an example of what the content looks like, and how you want to display it on your site.

Comment: yes, RSS is the best solution.

Comment: it will likely result in a mess anyway. If have to do that, your design is flawed in the first place.

Comment: @Lo'oris content syndication and aggregation is nothing uncommon.

Answer (score 5):

some of web hosting has disabled "readfile" function. But you can use "file_get_contents" function.

```
$home = file_get_contents('example.com');
echo $home;
```

Answer (score 2):

Any PHP function that can fetch remote URLs can help you with that. This can be as simple as doing

```
readfile('http://example.com'); // outputs contents of URL
```

If you need to [scrape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120/html-scraping-in-php) only some contents of a URL or want to postprocess the content, consider using [DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731531/how-to-use-phps-dom-extension-loadhtml). In case you are trying to parse a specific XML format like RSS, use a parser specialized for that format. If there is no parser for that format, use [XSLT](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) to transform it to HTML.

As for database access, why not ask the owner of the remote site and database if and how you may access it.

Like the comments below your question already suggested, if you can be more specific about the problem, we can be more specific about a solution.

Comment: ...but do implement some server-side caching!

Comment: @symcbean Could you be a little more specific? Give an example, technique name, etc.