# Parsing Table from another website

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display content of one site in another using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735534/how-to-display-content-of-one-site-in-another-using-php)

I need to display tide data on a website I am creating, I don't have any access to API's for such data so I was wondering if it is possible to take the table on this page: http://www.bom.gov.au/cgi-bin/oceanography/tides/tide_predications.cgi?location=SA_61900&tide_hiddenField=South%20Australia&years=2012&months=Oct&dates=16 and display it on my own page with the ability to reformat it so it looks pretty.
Would it be possible to do this with PHP or Java?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. With PHP. Also with Java, but you presumably meant Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this php library [SimpleHtml Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Follow the documentation it is pretty self explanatory

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.bom.gov.au/cgi-b...');

foreach($html->find('table') as $table) {
   // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php function getHTML($url){ //inisialisation CURL

$data = curl_init();

// setting CURL

curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// run CURL to read file

$value = curl_exec($data);

curl_close($data);

return $value;

}

?>
```

I hope it can help your problem..:)